Excel VBA - how to Delete multiple Rows from excel sheet
I have a dataset that is 1 column by 470,000 rows. It has three sections that store the data informations(DATA, RESET, CHECK).
My goal :

Find mismatched Label Name stored in "DATA" sheet with data listed on a separate sheet(LABEL_LIST) and delete them.
When mismatched data found, offset(-1,0) to obtain "/begin DATA" value and select rows till "/end DATA" value (total 13 rows) and delete them.
Number of Rows to delete from each section is for DATA section - 13, RESET - 6, CHECK - 5 rows.

My code has couple of loops to check unmatched label name from each section.However, it slow down the programming. And also here are some problems i am facing and trying to solve them.

when checking for unmatched label name loop in each section does not work as i wanted.
For example if label name "XYZ" from LABEL_LIST is unmatched with data stored in DATA sheet it delete all the data including those data that might be a match for next label from LABEL_LIST.
Number of rows to delete are different for each sections. That why i have separated loop for each section but it slows down excel
Is there any way to efficiently check the unmatched data? Thank you in advance.

source file structure :
here is my code :
Sub Delete_Rows()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, a As Long, r As Long
    Dim Lbl_name_row As Long, row As Long
    Dim keyword1 As String, keyword2 As String, keyword3 As String
    Dim Search_Lbl As Variant, Lbl_name As Variant

    Dim cell_DATA As Range, cell_RESET As Range, cell_CHECK As Range
    Dim Stcell_DATA As Range, Endcell_DATA As Range, 
    Dim Stcell_CHECK As Range, Endcell_CHECK As Range
    Dim Stcell_RESET As Range, Endcell_RESET As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA")

keyword1 = "/* @ DATA Section */"
keyword2 = "/* @ RESET Section */"
keyword3 = "/* @ CHECK Section */"
keywor4 = "/* @ VB Section */"

With Worksheets("DATA").Range("A4:A5000")
    Set cell_DATA = .Find(what:=keyword1, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    Set cell_RESET = .Find(what:=keyword2, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    Set cell_CHECK = .Find(what:=keyword3, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    Set cell_VB = .Find(what:=keyword4, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
End With

Set Stcell_DATA = cell_DATA.Offset(2, 0)
Set Endcell_DATA = cell_RESET.Offset(-1, 0)

Set Stcell_RESET = cell_RESET.Offset(2, 0)
Set Endcell_RESET = cell_CHECK.Offset(-1, 0)

Set Stcell_CHECK = cell_DATA.Offset(2, 0)
Set Endcell_CHECK = cell_VB.Offset(-1, 0)

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LABEL_LIST")
    ' check Lbl_name in DATA sheet
With Worksheet("DATA").Range(Stcell_DATA, Endcell_DATA)
    Lbl_name_row = 1
    For r = 1 To 250
        Lbl_name_row = Lbl_name_row + 1
        Search_Lbl = Worksheets("LABEL_LIST").Cells(Lbl_name_row, 1)
            For i = Stcell_DATA To Endcell_DATA
                Set Lbl_name = .Find(what:=Search_Lbl & "/*LABEL Name */", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
                    If Lbl_name Is Nothing Then
                        ws.Cells(i, 1).Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Select
                        ws.Rows(i & ":" & i + 11).Delete
                        ws.Cells(i, 1).Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
                    Else
                    End If
            Next i
        Next r
End With

With Worksheet("DATA").Range(Stcell_RESET, Endcell_RESET)
    Lbl_name_row = 1
    For r = 1 To 250
        Lbl_name_row = Lbl_name_row + 1
        Search_Lbl = Worksheets("LABEL_LIST").Cells(Lbl_name_row, 1)
            For i = Stcell_RESET To Endcell_RESET
                Set Lbl_name = .Find(what:=Search_Lbl & "/*LABEL Name */", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
                    If Lbl_name Is Nothing Then
                        ws.Cells(i, 1).Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Select
                        ws.Rows(i & ":" & i + 4).Delete
                        ws.Cells(i, 1).Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
                    Else
                    End If
            Next i
        Next r
End With

With Worksheet("DATA").Range(Stcell_CHECK, Endcell_CHECK)
    Lbl_name_row = 1
    For r = 1 To 250
        Lbl_name_row = Lbl_name_row + 1
        Search_Lbl = Worksheets("LABEL_LIST").Cells(Lbl_name_row, 1)
            For i = Stcell_CHECK To Endcell_CHECK
                Set Lbl_name = .Find(what:=Search_Lbl & "/*LABEL Name */", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
                    If Lbl_name Is Nothing Then
                        ws.Cells(i, 1).Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Select
                        ws.Rows(i & ":" & i + 3).Delete
                        ws.Cells(i, 1).Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
                    Else
                    End If
            Next i
        Next r
End With
End Sub
        


Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.
How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
Please create MD table with online tool Table Generator.

@taller thank you for your suggestions. i will do it.

Just as a note when deleting rows in a loop you generally want to go from the bottom to the top, because as you delete rows, the row numbers change (row 5 will become row 4 if you delete row 4 ... and now when you increment 4 to 5 on your counter, the old row 5 is "skipped")

It would likely be much faster to read your data into an array, and then loop over that array, writing non-skipped lines to a second array.  You removed your sample data, so I'm not able to try that out....

@TimWilliams i have just shared my source file here :https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kr6nfOe3uFUKPIadES5cuSCDGIOn_HnG/edit#gid=883490375
i would really appreciate if you could help me out with this.

Try this out.  It uses two arrays for processing, and writes the processed data to column F.
Sub RemoveRows()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim data, dataOut, ub As Long
    Dim i As Long, r As Long, v As String, lbl As String, sEnd As String, inc As Boolean
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA")
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LABEL_LIST")

    'adding one blank row for easier looping
    data = ws.Range("A1:A" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row + 1).Value
    ub = UBound(data, 1) '# of rows
    ReDim dataOut(1 To ub, 1 To 1) 'size output array
    
    i = 0
    r = 1
    
    Do While r <= ub
        v = Trim(data(r, 1))
        inc = True
        Select Case v
            Case "/begin DATA", "/begin RESET", "/begin CHECK"
                lbl = Trim(Replace(data(r + 1, 1), "/*LABEL Name */", "")) 'get the label
                'label doesn't match a known value?
                If IsError(Application.Match(lbl, ws1.Columns("A"), 0)) Then
                    Debug.Print "Dropping section '" & v & "' for label '" & lbl & "'"
                    inc = False 'do not write
                    sEnd = Replace(v, "/begin", "/end") 
                    Do 'skip forward to "/end xxxx"
                        r = r + 1
                        If r > ub Then Exit Do
                    Loop While data(r, 1) <> sEnd
                End If
        End Select

        If inc Then   'writing this line?
            i = i + 1
            dataOut(i, 1) = v
        End If

        r = r + 1 'next row
    Loop
    
    'write the output array
    With ws.Range("F1").Resize(ub, 1)
        .NumberFormat = "@"
        .Value = dataOut
    End With
End Sub

Format 2:
Do While r <= ub
        v = data(r, 1)
        inc = True
        Select Case Trim(Replace(v, vbTab, ""))
            Case "/begin DATA", "/begin RESET", "/begin CHECK"
            
                lbl = ExtractLabel(data(r + 1, 1))
                Debug.Print "Label: |" & lbl & "|"
                
                'label doesn't match a known value?
                If IsError(Application.Match(lbl, ws1.Columns("A"), 0)) Then
                    Debug.Print "Dropping section '" & v & "' for label '" & lbl & "'"
                    inc = False 'do not write
                    sEnd = Replace(v, "/begin", "/end")
                    Do 'skip forward to "/end xxxx"
                        r = r + 1
                        If r > ub Then Exit Do
                    Loop While data(r, 1) <> sEnd
                End If
        End Select
        If inc Then   'writing this line?
            i = i + 1
            dataOut(i, 1) = v
        End If
        r = r + 1 'next row
    Loop

and
Function ExtractLabel(txt)
    Dim lbl As String
    lbl = Replace(txt, vbTab, "") 'remove tabs
    lbl = Replace(lbl, """", "")  'remove quotes
    lbl = Replace(lbl, "/* LABEL", "/*LABEL") 'normalize space/no space
    lbl = Split(lbl, "/*LABEL")(0)
    ExtractLabel = Trim(lbl)
End Function


Thank you it worked perfectly, really appreciate it. Again i have a another dataset and need to delete unmatched Label name. But the structure is little bit different. For example: there is TAB space at the front and also between text ⇨ at name of section : "  /* @@@  DATA Section */" ,
at beginning of DATA : "  /begin DATA" ,  at LABEL Name : "   DIFF ""   /*LABEL Name  */"

I tried to modify the provided code but loop does not pass through Select Case.
modified code :


Case "vbtab" & "vbtab" & "/begin DATA", "vbtab" & "vbtab" & "/begin RESET", "vbtab" & "vbtab" & "/begin CHECK"


lbl = Trim("vbtab" & "vbtab" & "vbtab" & Replace(data(r + 1, 1), "vbtab" & """" & "vbtab" & "vbtab" & "vbtab" & "/*LABEL Name" & "vbtab" & "*/", ""))


New source DATA file : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c6M25DAUxjGbqgYnnbZxSPDzLS1Yllmy/edit#gid=452531010

could you please explain this step:  If IsError(Application.Match(lbl, ws1.Columns("A"), 0)) Then                     Debug.Print "Dropping section '" & v & "' for label '" & lbl & "'"

And these also  Debug.Print "Label: |" & lbl & "|"  and  .NumberFormat = "@" .

Application.Match is checking Col A for the exact value lbl - if there's no match then it will return an error value, so we test for that.  If there's an error returned it means the label isn't in your list.   Debug.Print is just for double-checking we managed to extract the correct label - the pipes (|) wrap the value so we can see if we got any extra whitespace by mistake.   @ is the number format for "Text" since your data is really all text...

i appreciate the explanation, it worked perfectly!


oDic is a Dict object used to store lable list
oDicSkip is a Dict object used to store the row count for each section (DATA, RESET, CHECK). It saves time to locate the end of sections. Feel free to expand the list as needed.
btw, CHECK - 5 rows is a typo in your post. Based on the sample data, it should be 8 rows.

Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim oDic As Object, oDicSkip As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, sTxt As String, iStart As Long, iR As Long
    Dim arrData, aKeys, aVals, arrRes, sSection As String
    Dim oSht1 As Worksheet, oSht2 As Worksheet
    Const START_ROW = 4
    Set oSht1 = Sheets("Data")
    Set oSht2 = Sheets("LABEL_LIST")
    ' load rows count into Dict
    Set oDicSkip = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    aKeys = Array("DATA", "RESET", "CHECK")
    aVals = Array(13, 6, 8)
    For i = 0 To UBound(aKeys)
        oDicSkip(aKeys(i)) = aVals(i)
    Next
    ' load LABEL_LIST into Dict
    Set oDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    arrData = oSht2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        oDic(arrData(i, 1)) = ""
    Next
    Set rngData = oSht1.Range("A1", oSht1.Cells(oSht1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    arrData = rngData.Value
    ReDim arrRes(1 To UBound(arrData), 0)
    ' loop through data rows
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
'        Debug.Print i
        ' Get the section name
        If arrData(i, 1) Like "/[*] @*Section [*]/" Then
            sSection = Split(arrData(i, 1))(2)
        End If
        ' locate the /begin row
        If arrData(i, 1) Like "/begin [A-Z]*" And i > START_ROW Then
            If i + 1 < UBound(arrData) Then
                ' get label name
                aKeys = Split(arrData(i + 1, 1)) ' xxxx /*LABEL Name */
                If oDic.Exists(aKeys(0)) Then ' match
                    For j = 0 To oDicSkip(sSection) - 1
                        iR = iR + 1
                        arrRes(iR, 0) = arrData(i + j, 1)
                    Next
                End If
                i = i + oDicSkip(sSection) - 1
            End If
        Else
            ' populate the output
            iR = iR + 1
            arrRes(iR, 0) = arrData(i, 1)
        End If
    Next
    ' write output to sheet
    Sheets.Add
    Range("A1").Resize(iR, 1) = arrRes
End Sub


Thank you. I really appreciate your help. I am trying to do the same thing (delete unmatched data) for new dataset but it has different structure. For example: there is TAB space at the front and also between text .
i have modified some code from provided code. but it does not pass through loop.
modified code :

If arrData(i, 1) Like "vbtab & vbtab" & "/[*] @*Section [*]/" Then
If arrData(i, 1) Like "vbtab & vbtab" & "/begin [A-Z]*" And i > START_ROW Then

New source DATA file : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c6M25DAUxjGbqgYnnbZxSPDzLS1Yllmy/edit#gid=452531010

Try If arrData(i, 1) Like vbTab & vbTab & "/[*] @*Section [*]/" Then. vbTab is a const in VBA.

in this step aKeys = Split(arrData(i + 1, 1)) ' xxxx /*LABEL Name */  also it does not get label names. In source data label names also has TAB space in the beginning.

Try aKeys = Split(arrData(i + 1, 1), vbTab)
